# GADBannerViewDelegate.h file not found in TOLAdAdapterAdMobAds.h

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I got `GADBannerViewDelegate`.h file not found error in TOLAdAdapterAdMobAds.h although i have already included that file as shown in image below. I have used

```
pod 'LARSAdController', '~> 3.0'
```

to install the pod file for it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
#import "GADBannerViewDelegate.h"
#import "GADBannerView.h"
```

with

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
```

This has to be done as GoogleMobileAds SDK is now a framework instead of static library.

After making this change, you may get an error at `request.testing = YES;` in `TOLAdAdapterGoogleAds.m`. To correct that, just replace that line with: `request.testDevices = @[kGADSimulatorID];` and everything should work fine.