# Lexical or preprocessor issue after I install podfile for HexColors (2.3.0)

Tags: ios, xcode6, cocoapods

I got `lexical or preprocessor issue` for HexColors (2.3.0) after I install the podfile for TSMessages

[image: Screenshot]

**I have got my pod file as below** and **pod 'TSMessages'** automatically is installing **HexColors (2.3.0)**

[image]

**I got installation process as below**

[image]

I have followed following links but doesn't make any sense

[lexical or preprocessor issue file not found occurs while archiving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925539/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-occurs-while-archiving)

[Link 2](http://kttailor4u.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-solve-lexical-or-preprocessor.html)

[Link 3](http://www.widecodes.com/0HHVjVPeUW/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-occurs-while-archiving.html)

[Link 4](http://www.widecodes.com/CmVjqXgqVP/workspace-sub-project-cocoa-pods-lexical-preprocessor-issue.html)

[Link 5](http://www.tech.theplayhub.com/lexical_or_preprocessor_issue_file_not_found_occurs_while_archiving/)

[Link 6](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/issues/80)

[Link 7](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/)

[Link 8](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restkit/qg9iC7Ncy-U)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [this project](https://github.com/mRs-/HexColors), then the header file is called `HexColors.h`, not `HexColor.h`

Comment: i got this issue after i install TSMessages

Comment: You would have got it before as well, as you are using the wrong file name.

Comment: I still see `#import "HexColor.h"` in the question.

Comment: have got my pod file as and and pod 'TSMessages' automatically is installing HexColors (2.3.0)

Comment: You don't appear to understand what I'm saying to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82718/discussion-between-nischal-hada-and-droppy).

Comment: thanks due i got nw I don't know why was it taking #import "HexColor.h" instead of #import "HexColors.h" by default after i installed pod . Any way my trouble is solved

Comment: any ideas ab this problem too dude  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715311/gadbannerviewdelegate-h-file-not-found-in-toladadapteradmobads-h  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703234/how-can-i-solve-coredata-mogenerator-not-found-issue

Comment: any idea ab these problems dude

Comment: dude did u check my other questions